# How to go from list to list of tuples in python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

My goal is to create a area graph in python. And for that I need a list of tuples as in the following example.

I have this list:

```
outputs=[25,50,60,45]
```

and I would like to distribute each value in the following list of tuples:

```
a=(25,0,0,0)
b=(0,50,0,0)
c=(0,0,60,0)     
d=(0,0,0,45)    
    
    # repeat the tupples on the following list:
data= [a,a,b,b,c,c,d,d]
```

pS: This data will allow to set the 2 upper corners (so the yy axis) of the area graph for each category on xx axis.

Comment: Just write a loop over `outputs`, create the relevant tuple, and append it twice to `data`.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want the N-th element of the list to become the N-th element in a n-tuple?

Comment: `[tuple((0,) * x + (i,) + (0,) * (len(outputs) - x - 1)) for x, i in enumerate(outputs)]` would get you your a/b/c/d variables.

Comment: AKX - I will edit it and try to reopen. TY

Comment: Is it always exactly four values?

Answer (score 1):

one line, double comprehension matching the indices of the diagonal, and repeat tuple twice.

```
[tuple(x if i==j else 0 for i in range(4)) for j,x in enumerate(outputs) for _ in range(2) ]
```

output:

```
[(25, 0, 0, 0),
 (25, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 50, 0, 0),
 (0, 50, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 60, 0),
 (0, 0, 60, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 45),
 (0, 0, 0, 45)]
```

Not the most efficient though since it builds the tuple twice.

Comment: I wouldn't reopen this, and agree with deceze's closure. There is a clear series of logical steps to follow, and I can't tell specifically where OP is stuck. Any individual part of the process is surely a duplicate question or else not a clear question that other people could realistically have. The overall question may be an *easy* "work order", but it still is one.

Comment: path crossed as I just reopened to let others propose their solutions (else it's unfair)

Comment: Now it's unfair to all the other "gimme codez" questions…

Comment: @deceze But do we care about that/them?

Comment: @KellyBundy Why do we care about this one in particular?

Comment: @deceze I think JFF cared about fairness to other potential *answerers* here. Or if you mean why we cared enough to answer this particular question: I can only speak for myself, my reason was that I felt like I had something interesting enough to share (mainly the technique of using a template list from which to produce the tuples after minimal modifications).

Answer (score 1):

A fast one for arbitrary `outputs` lengths:

```
a = [0] * len(outputs)
data = []
for i, a[i] in enumerate(outputs):
    t = *a,
    data += t, t
    a[i] = 0
```

Benchmark (not that it matters, and Jean-François Fabre didn't try to make theirs fast, but I like optimizing/benchmarking and I want to support my "fast" claim):

```
  0.44 ± 0.00 μs  Kelly_always4
  1.50 ± 0.00 μs  Kelly
  8.33 ± 0.02 μs  Jean_François_Fabre
```

Code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVNNj9MwED1wy6-Y29qLKW7VVqiSr3uAnxBFkdPY4CVxItuBrar9JVz2Apy5c4I7VyR-Df5I0m7V9FDNG8-bN8_jL9_6g_vQ6aenr4OTr978e_FXmq4Fp1qhHKi274wboyxmrONOWaf2dsq2gmvi8Vp8yrJaSHgnmuaAusH1g7N4l4H_ODDIaQG30Ag952Kq5i5mixjJzoAiwHNVgNIg9NAKw5244Auf81W3nMxxJHrJwBFwMxiJGNAIGOEGo-PBM6klbz7zg11fSiYV2ZOajWjCGOKEhl_SXjFE_bE53oeY-jKKY_c0YAIpqfGMjUpyTkKb0Mi3InWRZL31lpZ3huvf3ztlyztemUsDJgI39I1AD6AkKMbuQTRWAE02BgM9yXuB1hhH6J48XHc1ZstTwQqD1yIH7e-ZJZvIc7fIVZVZNjKGG11tyIaSLSXrTSDzHWToEFnTFL1R2iE5y8BZFpYtVB_lzu8EPK96jPaEHbRIjk6kXs6v1lJs43kXzlu_m6JGkS6XBc53S1oU597Jm2PYXRQ83S5W8hF-_YBjXOSIrSP256eFm6T-zJ8lpWP7a2NN25keDmp4W9V8B6c5CfgbqIRhgQdeg_87FY6KF7zvhfYT4DPvxqliLwIfxYFFM_C5nZM9BOSiLDVvRVni9L7HZz499_8)):

```py
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev

def Kelly(outputs):
    a = [0] * len(outputs)
    data = []
    for i, a[i] in enumerate(outputs):
        t = *a,
        data += t, t
        a[i] = 0
    return data

def Kelly_always4(outputs):
    a,b,c,d=outputs
    a=(a,0,0,0)
    b=(0,b,0,0)
    c=(0,0,c,0)     
    d=(0,0,0,d)    
    return [a,a,b,b,c,c,d,d]

def Jean_François_Fabre(outputs):
    return [tuple(x if i==j else 0 for i in range(4)) for j,x in enumerate(outputs) for _ in range(2) ]

funcs = Kelly, Kelly_always4, Jean_François_Fabre

outputs = [25,50,60,45]

for f in funcs:
    print(f(outputs))

times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e6 for t in sorted(times[f])[:10]]
    return f'{mean(ts):6.2f} ± {stdev(ts):4.2f} μs '

for _ in range(100):
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: f(outputs), number=100) / 100
        times[f].append(t)

for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `enumerate()` function to find the index of each element and correspond it to the index of the tuple:

```
data = []

for index, value in enumerate(outputs):
    l = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    l[index] = value
    
    l = tuple(l)

    data.append(l)
    data.append(l)
```

Output:

```
[(25, 0, 0, 0), 
 (25, 0, 0, 0), 
 (0, 50, 0, 0), 
 (0, 50, 0, 0), 
 (0, 0, 60, 0), 
 (0, 0, 60, 0), 
 (0, 0, 0, 45), 
 (0, 0, 0, 45)]
```

This method loops through all the values of the outputs and keeps track of the values index with the `enumerate()` function. Then, create a temporary list l and set all the values to 0, EXCEPT the value at the index. Finally, it converts the list to a tuple by using the `tuple()` function and adds it to the data list using the `append()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You could build the tuples by extracting a subset of a padded tuple that has the number in the middle:

```
outputs = [25,50,60,45]
    
data = [(0,0,0,n,0,0,0)[3-i:7-i] for i,n in enumerate(outputs) for _ in ".."]
   
print(*data,sep="\n")

(25, 0, 0, 0)
(25, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 50, 0, 0)
(0, 50, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 60, 0)
(0, 0, 60, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 45)
(0, 0, 0, 45)
```

You could generalize this to work with any size of 'outputs' list by setting up the padding based on the size of the original list:

```
s    = len(outputs)
pad  = [0]*s*2
data = [tuple(pad[s-i:2*s-i]) for i,pad[s] in enumerate(outputs) for _ in ".."]
```

Comment: I had considered something similar: building the tuple (25,0,0,0,50,0,0,0,60,0,0,0,45) via a list and with slice assignment and then slicing from that. But dismissed it when I had my other idea.